# mod_auth_ldap mod_rewrite set username as cookie

Tags: mod-rewrite, cookies

I have an .htaccess file that authenticates users against LDAP using `mod_auth_ldap`. My requirement is to somehow store their username and use it elsewhere**. I think I may be able to do it with `mod_rewrite` and cookies.

```
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthType Basic
AuthName "xxx"
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off

AuthLDAPUrl "xxx" NONE
AuthLDAPBindDN "xx"
AuthLDAPBindPassword xx

Require valid-user
```

--

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(username)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,CO=username:%{USERNAME}:.domain.com]
```

If anyone wants to tell me cookies is a rubbish idea and has a better one, please do.

Many thanks.

** I note there are security implications by using a username from a cookie but in my app this acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic variable was %{REMOTE_USER}.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !username
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L,CO=username:%{REMOTE_USER}:.domain.com]
```